# Angular 6 - Value of ngModel Appears only when clicked somewhere

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, angular6, ngmodel

I have a component, that displays a list of items. On every item, there is a dropdown with which you can change a value. The only issue is, that when creating the component, the selected item in the dropdown is empty. *It appears only if I click anywhere on the page.*

**Typescript**

```
export class Component {

    @Input() files: ProductFile[];

    contentTypes: { [id: string]: string } = {};

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.files.forEach(f => this.contentTypes[f._id] = f.contentType);
    }

    public fileTypes: string[] = [/* items in the dropdown */];

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div
    *ngFor="let f of files"
    class="file shadow"
>
    <dy-dropdown
        [items]="fileTypes"
        [ngModel]="contentTypes[f._id]"
        (ngModelChange)="onUpdate($event, f)"
    ></dy-dropdown>
</div>
```

P.S.: `dy-dropdown` is a custom Form Control which simply changes the value when the user selects an item in the dropdown list.

Comment: have you tried using a select instead of your custom form control, could be the issue is in there.

Comment: I would definitely try the above suggestion to see if the problem is this control before spending a lot more time on this.

Comment: that's a great idea! I will try it tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: It worked! I now have to figure out where the problem with the dropdown is

Answer (score 1):

Try calling detection changes manually using **[`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from 'angular/core';

constructor(private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef){

}
```

and call inside your onUpdate function

```
this.chRef.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be, you need to trigger change detection manually.Here is the code.

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.files.forEach(f => this.contentTypes[f._id] = f.contentType);
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: why are you posting same answer again?

Comment: It might happen parallely both may be submit at same time. Can you please create stackblitz.